# How to find the frequency (weekly,monthly) of a user inserts a row into the database based on 2 time intervals

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssms

I am working on a report and I need to find how frequent a user insert a row in database based on a interval ( @startDate,@finalDate) i pick from a UI.

For example : 
I have the interval  : 05/25/2019  -  06/13/2019

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[BT_Test_Procedure_With_Period] 
@beginDate DateTime,
@endDate DateTime
AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT name, COUNT(*) as 'nrOfRows',
CASE
WHEN COUNT(*)  >= DATEDIFF(WEEK, @beginDate, @endDate) THEN 'x'
ELSE ''
END AS 'Weekly',
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >=DATEDIFF(WEEK, @beginDate, @endDate)/4  AND COUNT(*) 
<DATEDIFF(WEEK, @beginDate, @endDate) THEN 'x' 
ELSE ''
END AS 'Montly',
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >1 AND COUNT(*) <DATEDIFF(WEEK, @beginDate, 
@endDate)/4 THEN 'x'
ELSE ''
END AS 'Rare',
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 'x'
ELSE ''
END AS 'One time'  FROM InsertedRecords
WHERE @InsertedDateRow BETWEEN @beginDate AND @endDate
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY nrOfRows DESC
```

If the user has inserted at least one row per each week in this interval the frequency will be : weekly.
Or if it insert at least one row per each month in this interval but not in each week the frequency will be : monthly

My question here is : how do i check in each week and month from the current interval to see if @rowInsertedDate is in there?

In this given case  05/25/2019  -  06/13/2019 , there are 3 valid weeks in which the user can insert the row : 
27 May - 02 June 
03 June - 09 June
10 June - 13 June

If the user insert a row in each of of these 3 : weekly ,else monthly .

I hope i was clear enough , thank you !

Comment: Extract the DATEPART needed and COUNT (DISTINCT ..).

Comment: What would you determine a user that inserted every 31 days?  They could insert 3 times in a row and be within 3 distinct months, but at some point they will skip a month like February altogether.  The variable length of months make this a difficult problem without further clarification from yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) as 'nrOfRows',
    CASE
    WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT DATEPART(wk, @InsertedDateRow))  >= DATEDIFF(WEEK, @beginDate, @endDate) THEN 'x'
    ELSE ''
    END AS 'Weekly',
 -- ..
FROM InsertedRecords
WHERE @InsertedDateRow BETWEEN @beginDate AND @endDate
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: I think this should just be a `>` instead of a `>=` as your `datediff` returns the number of week boundaries crossed, not the number of weeks.  A date period that is 9 days long can cover 3 different weeks, but a `datediff(week...` for that same period will return `2`.

Comment: @iamdave .. Hihgly probably you are right, but let OP decide on exact logic of the query. What if only the whole weeks count, so 9 days is never more then 1 week.

Comment: In that case, a date period of Wednesday to Monday would be `0` whole weeks but a `datediff` of `1`.  Either way, the `datediff` solution is fraught with potential pitfalls

Comment: The problem with DISTINCT DATEPART is that in this period :  StartDate 2019-01-19   , EndDate 2019-02-27 ,there are 4 WeekNumbers 6,7,8,9  but the DateDiff returns  a total of 6 Weeks, so therefore even if the user has inserted a row in each of those 4 weeks, the frequency will not be weekly .

Comment: @VasileViorel , `select distinct datepart(wk, dt) dp
from ( values ('2019-01-22'),('2019-01-29')
   ,('2019-02-05'),('2019-02-12'),('2019-02-19'),('2019-02-26')) t(dt)` returns 6 rows. Why 4 ?